# Is there a security risk associated with defining multiple "params" in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, strong-parameters

I am new to rails and making myauthentication/authorization system since devise was way overkill for what I needed. I realize that since I am not a security expert it will probably have holes. I have tested to the best of my knowledge whether the following would present a security issue, but maybe someone more experienced would be kind enough to give me their two cents :)

Here's the code, it is pretty self explanatory what I'm trying to do:

```
def user_params
      if is_super_user
        params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role_id)
      else
        params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
      end
    end
```

So a regular user should not be able to alter permissions levels whereas a super user can. Is this okay to do? Is there a better solution?

Comment: No, there's nothing wrong with that code.

Comment: Except that it's not very DRY.

Comment: Thank you for the help, any recommendations on how to dry-ify it? As I mentioned I'm new to this.